# Suggestion Required - Software to Convert .xlsx to .mdb

Tags: ms-access-2007, ms-access-2003

Does anyone know a software which converts .xlsx (Excel) to .mdb (MS Access). Freeware or otherwise.
I tried PDS (Trial Version) , but doesn't look like it works well.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access. That is the right way to go. Or you can use http://www.zamzar.com/

Comment: Zamzar..Not sure whether my data will be safe as I don't want any third party to gather this data.